# How to add/edit a virtual network by REST API

Tags: networking, azure, virtual

I can add a new virtual network in management portal.

But how can I do it programmatically?

[The api here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157182) confused me, I can only set the configuration of all VNets? It's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, currently the only operations supported through the REST API for Virtual Networks are:

1. Get Network Configuration
2. List Virtual Network Sites
3. Set Network Configuration

You might try Azure Powershell, as it has many options for [controlling Virtual Networks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj863582.aspx)

Its also rather simple to [setup Azure Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554332.aspx), and to [run Powershell in your c# project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C).

Hopefully, these commands will be added to the REST api in [future versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg592580.aspx).

Comment: Is there any REST API which can be helpful for creating new Virtual Network on Azure? Also "controlling Virtual Networks" link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj863582.aspx) is not working now..

Answer (score 0):

you can

using powershell and create funtion

SetAzureVNetConfig(string filepath)

List commands = new List();

```
            commands.Add(string.Format("Set-AzureVNetConfig -ConfigurationPath \"{0}\"", FilePath));

            PowershellEventArgs e = ps_.RunComands(commands);
```